# How do I grep a exact string from multiple files at the same time?

Tags: scripts, grep

I have multiple files(text file) in a folder like below where the 1st file contains some paths as a string and the other with path+file_name.

**File1:**

```
# pwd
/root/test
# cat file1.txt
/abc/bce/12345/input/part3
/abc/bce/12345/input/part3/err
/abc/bce/34563/input
/abc/bce/34563/input/part1
/abc/bce/34563/input/part3/wrk
/abc/bce/11198/input/VII
/abc/bce/11198/input/VII/err
/abc/bce/11198/input/VII/part3
/abc/bce/11198/input/VII/part3/err
#
```

**File2:**

```
# pwd
/root/test/test
# cat file2.txt
/abc/bce/12345/input/part3/AIR9905.txt--20210421--
/abc/bce/12345/input/part3/AIR9923.txt--20210315--
/abc/bce/12345/input/part3/err/AIR9950.txt--20200512--
#
```

**File3:**

```
# pwd
/root/test/test
# cat file3.txt
/abc/bce/12345/input/part3/err/AIR1034.txt--20210110--
/abc/bce/34563/input/part1/AIR3426.txt--20200420--
/abc/bce/11198/input/VII/part3/err/V.AIR7650.txt--20170625--
#
```

**Present output:**

```
test/file2.txt:/abc/bce/12345/input/part3/AIR9905.txt--20210421--
test/file2.txt:/abc/bce/12345/input/part3/AIR9923.txt--20210315--
test/file2.txt:/abc/bce/12345/input/part3/err/AIR9950.txt--20200512--
test/file3.txt:/abc/bce/12345/input/part3/err/AIR1034.txt--20210110--
```

**Expected Output:**

```
test/file2.txt:/abc/bce/12345/input/part3/AIR9905.txt--20210421--
test/file2.txt:/abc/bce/12345/input/part3/AIR9923.txt--20210315--
```

I am using `grep -rHw "/abc/bce/12345/input/part3" test/` to match the line from file1 and extract their info from file2,file3,.... so on. However the problem lies, when I take the 1st line from file1 and try to retrieve the path+File_name, it takes all the similar lines from file2,file3, and so on. But I want to  get lines in file2.txt, file3.txt, ... that (a) contain the string "/abc/bce/12345/input/part3" + an added string (the filenames), but (b) don't contain the other "/abc/bce/12345/input/part3/err" string.

```
  I don't know how I can do that when file1 is being compared with multiple files in a continuous manner. I need a generalized solution for all cases. Please let me know if there are any other ways to get this done through the shell script.
```

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official *flavors* of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.  *You didn't mention OS & release, but from your pastes it appears you're asking about CentOS 7 which is off-topic here*

Comment: Also cross-posted here [How do I grep a exact string from multiple files at the same time](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/647511/how-do-i-grep-a-exact-string-from-multiple-files-at-the-same-time)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
find . -type f -name 'file[2-3].txt' -exec  grep -P '/abc/bce/12345/input/part3/(?!err)' {} \;
```

Comment: An easier way would probably be to use `grep --include='file[2-3].txt' -Pr ...`

Comment: Did it get downvoted because of my edit? I can revert my changes.

Answer (score 0):

It's called negative lookahead `(?!)`

```
grep -Pr '/abc/bce/12345/input/part3/(?!err)' test/
```

If you want to use file1.txt as a list of patterns:

```
grep -e err$ test/file1.txt | grep --include='file[2-3].txt' -vrFf - test/test
```

Comment: Thanks for the above command. `find -type f -name 'file[2-3].txt' -exec  grep -P '/abc/bce/12345/input/part3/(?!err)' {} +` works for me. But is there any way to pass variable instead of (?!err) in the command line. Because I have multiple lines in file1 if I followed this command then I have to modify each and every time the find command to get the result.